# Xcode 13 crashing when adding a dictionary to the Info.plist from a target

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode13

Xcode Version 13.3 beta 3 (13E5104i) or Version 13.2.1 (13C100)

When I add a dictionary to the Info.plist file from the Info tab in the project (for example with the Privacy - Location Temporary Usage Description Dictionary key), Xcode immediately crashes with the following message, that seems to be related to the type of new item added.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-20084/DVTFoundation/MacroExpansion/DVTMacroDefinitionTable.mm:1034
Details:  value must be nil, string or array, but is {
}
Object:   <DVTMacroDefinitionTable: 0x7fe3afb62ce0>
Method:   -_setLiteralValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:wantsCheckForDVTMacroExpansionConformance:
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x7fe3c480ed70>{number = 1, name = main}
Open FDs: 70/7168
Hints:
Backtrace:
0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
3   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable _setLiteralValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:wantsCheckForDVTMacroExpansionConformance:] (in DVTFoundation)
4   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable setLiteralValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:] (in DVTFoundation)
5   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] (in DVTFoundation)
6   __52-[PBXTarget _adjustBuildSettingsForProductSettings:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
7   __NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
8   -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
9   -[PBXTarget _adjustBuildSettingsForProductSettings:] (in DevToolsCore)
10   -[PBXTarget writeProductSettings:configuration:] (in DevToolsCore)
11   -[PBXTarget setProductSettings:configuration:] (in DevToolsCore)
12   -[PBXTarget setProductSettings:] (in DevToolsCore)
13   -[Xcode3ExtensionBasedInfoController setInfoDictionary:] (in Xcode3UI)
14   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
15   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
16   _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
17   __35-[Xcode3InfoEditor _createSubviews]_block_invoke (in Xcode3UI)
18   -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
19   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
20   NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
21   NSKeyValueDidChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications (in Foundation)
22   -[Xcode3InfoDictionarySliceController _mergeInfoDictionaries] (in Xcode3UI)
23   -[Xcode3InfoDictionarySliceController customPlistChanged:] (in Xcode3UI)
24   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
25   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
26   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
27   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
28   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
29   -[Xcode3InfoEditorPlistDocument propertyListChanged:] (in Xcode3UI)
30   -[DVTPlistModel _setPlistNoCopy:forKeyPath:atIndex:doReplace:doNotify:] (in DVTKit)
31   -[DVTPlistModel setKey:forPlist:] (in DVTKit)
32   -[DVTPlistModel setLocalizedKey:forPlist:] (in DVTKit)
33   -[DVTPlistViewController outlineView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:byItem:] (in DVTKit)
34   -[NSOutlineView _dataSourceSetValue:forColumn:row:] (in AppKit)
35   -[NSTableView _setNewObjectValueFromCell:ifNotEqualTo:forTableColumn:row:] (in AppKit)
36   -[NSTableView textDidEndEditing:] (in AppKit)
37   -[DVTPlistOutlineView textDidEndEditing:] (in DVTKit)
38   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
39   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
40   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
41   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
42   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
43   -[NSTextView(NSSharing) resignFirstResponder] (in AppKit)
44   -[NSWindow _realMakeFirstResponder:] (in AppKit)
45   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
46   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
47   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
48   -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
49   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
50   -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
51   -[NSApplication _handleEvent:] (in AppKit)
52   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
53   -[DVTApplication run] (in DVTKit)
54   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
55   start (in dyld)
ProductBuildVersion: 13E5104i
abort() called
```

Comment: Same for me. Looks like it happens only with NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescription

Comment: Did you maybe figured it out?

Answer (score 2):

try removing NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary from info.plist

Comment: It helped. But how to develop an app with geolocation services enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by moving the NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary from the auto-generated Info.plist (Targets -> *yourapp* -> Info tab) to the manual Info.plist.